# JetBrains Academy IntelliJ integration corrupted

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am following the Kotlin course and have managed to work through 75% of the course using the IntelliJ integration (shown below).

Somewhere along the way, IntelliJ stopped syncing with the JetBrains Academy course. I see the popup "Synchronizing JetBrains Academy Account" but nothing happens in the IDE.

Any idea what I should do to get he synchronization to work? Remove the Edutools plugin and re-install? Something else?

[image]

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling EduTools didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Log out from the JetBrains Academy account and log in back in **Settings/Preferences | Tools | Education** in your IDE.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. So I uninstalled Intellij and reinstalled it then re-authorized JetBrains academy and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling (and authorizing JetBrains Academy) and that fixed it.